# Not recieving confirmation email can anyone see whats up

Tags: php

for some reason the won't send mail to the admin also known as the 'carparks_accounts' can anyone help me with this? would it not be wiser to have this email send as an SMTP from just one email? if so how would i do this? could it be a problem with the listener?

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect("mysql", "", "");
    if(!$link) {
        die('Couldnt Connect To Server: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $db = mysql_select_db("");
    if(!$db) {
        die("Couldnt Connect To Database");
    }
    $sql6 = "UPDATE `discount_type` SET `name`='READ' WHERE `id`='1'";
    $results1 = mysql_query($sql6);



    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=' . urlencode('_notify-validate');

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }
        else if (is_array($value)) {
            $paymentArray = explode(' ', $value[0]);
            $paymentCurrency = urlencode(stripslashes($paymentArray[0]));
            $paymentGross = urlencode(stripslashes($paymentArray[1]));
            $req .= '&mc_currency=' . $paymentCurrency . '&mc_gross=' . $paymentGross;
        }
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.paypal.com'));

    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $custom = $_POST['custom'];



    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        // check the payment_status is Completed
        // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
        // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
        // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
        // process payment

      $sql6 = "UPDATE `discount_type` SET `name`='YES".$custom."' WHERE `id`='1'";
      $results1 = mysql_query($sql6);


      $bid = $custom;
      $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE `id`='".$bid."'");
      $row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1);

      $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='".$row1['uid']."'");
      $row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2);

      $sql3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users_address` WHERE `uid`='".$row1['uid']."'");
      $row3=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3);

      $sql4=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users_vehicles` WHERE `uid`='".$row1['uid']."'");
      $row4=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql4);

      $sql5=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `carparks_content` WHERE `cpid`='".$row1['cpid']."'");
      $row5=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql5);

      $sql8=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `bookings_details` WHERE `bid`='".$bid."'");
      $row8=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql8);

       $sql9=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `carparks` WHERE  `id` = '".$tow1['cpid']."'");
      $row9=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql8);


      $to      = $row2['email'];
      $subject = "SpeedyPark Booking Confirmation";
      $message = "<p>Hi, ".$row2['fname']."</p>";
      $message .= "<p>Thank you for booking your airport parking with SpeedyPark.</p>";
      $message .= "<p>Booking REF: <b>".$row9['uniqueRef'].str_pad ( $bid , 7 ,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT )."</b></p>";
      $message .= "<p>Name: <b>".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['sname']."</b></p>";
      $message .= "<p>Drop Off Dates: <b>".date('d/m/Y', $row1['sdate'])." - ".$row1['stime']."</b></p>";
      $message .= "<p>Pick Up Dates: <b>".date('d/m/Y', $row1['edate'])." - ".$row1['etime']."</b></p>";
      $message .= "<p>Outbound Flight: <b>Terminal ".$row8['terminalout']." - Flight ".$row8['flightout']."</b></p>";
      $message .= "<p>Return Flight: <b>Terminal ".$row8['terminalin']." - Flight ".$row8['flightin']."</b></p>";
      $message .= "<p>Price: <b>".$row1['price']."</b></p>";
      $message .= "<p>Phone: <b>".$row2['phone']."</b></p>";
      $message .= "<p>Email: <b>".$row2['email']."</b></p>";
      $message .= "<p>Address: <b>".$row3['address1'].", ".$row3['address2'].", ".$row3['city'].",".$row3['postcode']."</b></p>";
      $message .= "<p>Vehicle: <b>".$row4['reg']." - ".$row4['make']." ".$row4['model']." - ".$row4['colour']."</b></p>";
      if ($row1['cpeid'] == "") {

      } else {
        $message .= "<h3>Extras</h3>";
        $extralist = explode(', ', $row1['cpeid']);
        foreach($extralist as $value) //loop over values
        { 
        $sql17 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `carparks_extras` WHERE `id`='".$value."'");
        $row17 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql7);
          $message .= $row17['name']."<br/>";
        }
      }
      if ($row5['directions'] == "") { } else {
        $message .= "<h3>Directions</h3>";
        $message .= $row5['directions'];
      }
      if ($row5['arrival'] == "") { } else {
        $message .= "<h3>Arrival</h3>";
        $message .= $row5['arrival'];
      }
      if ($row5['departure'] == "") { } else {
        $message .= "<h3>Departure</h3>";
        $message .= $row5['departure'];
      }
      if ($row5['transfers'] == "") { } else {
        $message .= "<h3>Transfer</h3>";
        $message .= $row5['transfers'];
      }


      $headers = "From: reservation@speedypark.co.uk \r\n";
      $headers .= "Reply-To: reservation@speedypark.co.uk \r\n";
      $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
      mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

      $sql9=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `carparks_accounts` WHERE `cpid`='".$row1['cpid']."'");
      $row9=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql9);
      $to2      = $row9['email'];
      $subject2 = "New Airport Parking Booking Confirmation";
      $message2 .= "<p>Your car park has received a new booking through SpeedyPark.</p>";
      $message2 .= "<p>Booking ID: <b>".$bid."</b></p>";
      $message2 .= "<p>Name: <b>".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['sname']."</b></p>";
      $message2 .= "<p>Drop Off Dates: <b>".date('d/m/Y', $row1['sdate'])." - ".$row1['stime']."</b></p>";
      $message2 .= "<p>Pick Up Dates: <b>".date('d/m/Y', $row1['edate'])." - ".$row1['etime']."</b></p>";
      $message2 .= "<p>Outbound Flight: <b>Terminal ".$row8['terminalout']." - Flight ".$row8['flightout']."</b></p>";
      $message2 .= "<p>Return Flight: <b>Terminal ".$row8['terminalin']." - Flight ".$row8['flightin']."</b></p>";
      $message2 .= "<p>Price: <b>".$row1['price']."</b></p>";
      $message2 .= "<p>Vehicle: <b>".$row4['reg']." - ".$row4['make']." ".$row4['model']." - ".$row4['colour']."</b></p>";
      if ($row1['cpeid'] == "") {
      } else {
        $message2 .= "<h3>Extras</h3>";
        $extralist = explode(', ', $row1['cpeid']);
        foreach($extralist as $value) //loop over values
        { 
        $sql17 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `carparks_extras` WHERE `id`='".$value."'");
        $row17 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql7);
          $message2 .= $row17['name']."<br/>";
        }
      }
      $headers2 = "From: reservation@speedypark.co.uk \r\n";
      $headers2 .= "Reply-To: reservation@speedypark.co.uk \r\n";
      $headers2 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
      $headers2 .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
      mail($to2, $subject2, $message2, $headers2);
      $sql6 = "UPDATE `bookings` SET `status`='confirmed' WHERE `id`='".$bid."'";
      $results1 = mysql_query($sql6);
    }
    else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        // log for manual investigation
        $sql6 = "UPDATE `discount_type` SET `name`='NO' WHERE `id`='1'";
        $results1 = mysql_query($sql6);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please dont use the `mysql_` database extensions, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
[and here is some help to decide which to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Set error reporting level before and check the return value of the mail function for a start - also try to remove the spaces in the end of each row in the headers (as stated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php))

Comment: FYI, in the future please do not dump all of your code here. You must narrow it down to a smaller subset of relevant code only. If you have to post this much code, we have to assume you didn't even try to debug this which does not encourage us to help you.